# Wikidata - resultset.hasNext() returns false despite the results are retrieved

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, wikidata

As the title clearly describes, we `resultset.hasNext()` returns `false` unexpectedly.

**Here is my SPARQL query and Java source code based on Jena:**

```
SELECT ?s ?label WHERE { ?s rdfs:label ?label. FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?label), "university"@en)). } LIMIT 5

Query query = QueryFactory.create(PREFIX + sparqlQuery);
QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql", PREFIX + sparqlQuery);
try {
    ResultSet results = queryExecution.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    while (results.hasNext()) { // returns false
        QuerySolution querySolution = results.next();
        System.out.println(querySolution.getResource("s"));
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    queryExecution.close();
}
```

**Here is the output:**

```
------------------------------------------------------
| s        | label                                   |
======================================================
| wd:Q1060 | "Technical University of Hamburg"@en    |
| wd:Q1060 | "Technical University of Hamburg"@en-ca |
| wd:Q1060 | "Technical University of Hamburg"@en-gb |
| wd:Q1060 | "Technical University of Hamburg"@nl    |
| wd:Q4027 | "Jean Moulin University Lyon 3"@en      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only iterate once over the `Resultset`, and this already happens in the convenience method `ResultSetFormatter.out(...)`

I don't know whether you really need to process the `ResultSet` twice, but if so you can create a `ResultSetRewindable` which allows to reset the cursor:

```java
Query query = QueryFactory.create(PREFIX + sparqlQuery);
QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql", PREFIX + sparqlQuery);
try {
    ResultSet rs = queryExecution.execSelect();
    ResultSetRewindable results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(rs);
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    results.reset();
    while (results.hasNext()) { // returns false
        QuerySolution querySolution = results.next();
        System.out.println(querySolution.getResource("s"));
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    queryExecution.close();
}
```

Comment: I was not aware the cursor is not reset after the calling `ResultSetFormatter.out()` method.